# Error: docker login exited with 125, using heroku container:login

Tags: docker, heroku, containers, heroku-cli

I was trying to start a upload of a container to heroku, but when I use the command `heroku container:login`, it's returning a error:

```
heroku container:login                
unknown flag: --password-stdin
See 'docker login --help'.
▸    Error: docker login exited with 125
```

Here is the output of `docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

What I'm doing wrong, it's a error from docker or from heroku cli?

Some issues that I found about the subject: 
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-container-registry/issues/4

Comment: What is the full output of the `docker version` command?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU there it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-container-registry/pull/48) in the heroku plugin.

Upgrading your local docker to a version higher or equal to 17.07 will fix the problem.